# Como cambiar el proyecto que viene por default en la imagen One Click app para Ruby On Rails DigitalOcean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, digitalocean

necesito hacer deploy de mi propia aplicación en un servidor de DigitalOcean, tengo un droplet con la imagen One Click app para Ruby On Rails y trae por defecto una aplicacion vacia corriendo que se llama rails_project.

Yo necesito saber como cambiar la configuracion o que cambiar en la configuracion para empezar a usar mi propia aplicacion clonada desde mi repositorio.

He intentando varias cosas, como modificar los archivos /etc/unicorn.conf y  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/rails  pero aun sigo obtiendo el error 502. Ya no se que hacer, necesito ayuda.

Comment: Ocupas conectarte a la instancia via ssh, despues clonar tu projecto adentro del server y decirle al nginx que ahora tu projecto es el que levantara y no el que esta por default, hiciste esto?

Comment: si, hice eso pero aun asi me sigue aparaciendo el error 502.

Comment: hiciste bundle install y la version de ruby instalada en la maquina es la que usa tu proyecto?

Comment: si claro, instale la version 2.5.0 y la coloque como default.

Comment: checa los errores de log/produccion y de nginx /var/tmp/log/nginx a ver si te orienta un poco mas de donde esta el error.

Comment: Este link te podria ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51296932/how-to-change-the-default-project-that-comes-in-the-one-click-app-for-ruby-on-ra

Comment: @roxdurazo ese link, soy yo preguntando en la version en ingles de stackoverflow. Gracias de todas formas.

Comment: tienes razón, no me di cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

Buen dia

al acceder via ssh , hay un comando sudo -i -u rails ( cambias a usuario rails ) 
en el directorio de ese usuario , existe la app de pruebas "example"

con git puedes descargar tu projecto a esa carpeta , acto seguido , tienes que configurar ngnix para que apunte a ese proyecto.

te recomiento que leas la documentacion de digital ocean. 
https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/one-clicks/ruby-on-rails/